# I am trying to parse such a json in which use many arrays and dictionary. How to parse it in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, nested

I'm able to parse first three values. The nested values in dayWiseTimeSheet section i want to parse.

```
{"TimeSheet":
[
 {"day":"10-5-2016",
 "totalTravelTime":"1.40hrs",
 "totalWorkTime":"6hrs",
 "dayWiseTimeSheet": [{
                      "taskId": "101",
                      "travelingTime": "40 mins",
                      "workingTime": "3 hrs"
                      }, {
                      "taskId": "102",
                      "travelingTime": "1 hr",
                      "workingTime": "3 hrs"
                      }]
 },
 {"day":"11-5-2016",
 "totalTravelTime":"1.40hrs",
 "totalWorkTime":"6hrs",
 "dayWiseTimeSheet": [{
                      "taskId": "101",
                      "travelingTime": "50 mins",
                      "workingTime": "5 hrs"
                      }, {
                      "taskId": "102",
                      "travelingTime": "3 hr",
                      "workingTime": "7 hrs"
                      }]
 }
]
}
```

The code i have used is

```
for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in books )
{
    TimesheetInfo *tableObject = [[TimesheetInfo alloc]initwithday:
    [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"day"]
    totalTravelTime:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"totalTravelTime"]
    totalWorkTime:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"totalWorkTime"]
}
```

Comment: The `dayWiseTimeSheet` key will give you an array of dictionaries.

Comment: which value you want from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
NSMutableArray *allDayWiseTimeSheet = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in books )
{
    TimesheetInfo *tableObject = [[TimesheetInfo alloc]initwithday:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"day”]]]
    totalTravelTime:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"totalTravelTime"]
    totalWorkTime:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"totalWorkTime"]
    NSArray *dayWiseTimeSheet = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@“dayWiseTimeSheet”];

    for(NSDictionary *info in dayWiseTimeSheet)
    {
        [allDayWiseTimeSheet addObject:info];
        NSLog(@“%@”,[info valueForKey:@“taskId”]);
        NSLog(@“%@”,[info valueForKey:@“travelingTime”]);
        NSLog(@“%@”,[info valueForKey:@“workingTime”]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i am storing every key- value data in nsmutable array. How would i save dayWiseTimeSheet key-value in same NSMutable array.         
        TimesheetInfo *tableObject = [[TimesheetInfo alloc]initwithday:
        [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"day"]
        NSArray *dayWiseTimeSheet = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"dayWiseTimeSheet"];
       for(NSDictionary *info in dayWiseTimeSheet)
                                   { your code}
        [self.objectHolderArray addObject:tableObject];   
    }

Comment: You can add info dictionary in your NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the 3rd Key's Value into a dictionary with Data Type of Array with Anyobject Data Type

Later get every object from array into a entity class.

Let dict = response.objectforkey("dayWiseTimeSheet")

Answer (score 0):

if the data is a json ,maybe you must translate the json to nsdictionary ,then you can get the NSarry for the collecttion of model.

Comment: this should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON data the following code will parse "dayWiseTimeSheet" data. The type of the json should be dictionary not an array.

```
for (id obj in [[json valueForKey:@"TimeSheet"] valueForKey:@"dayWiseTimeSheet"]) {

NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"taskId"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"travelingTime"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"workingTime"]);
```

}